# Write a shell script to calculate the number of employees

Tags: bash, shell

I need to find the count of employees whose salary is less than average salary of all employees.

The file with the employee details will be given as a command line argument when your script will run
example->

Input: File:

```
empid;empname;salary
100;A;30000
102;B;45000
103;C;15000
104;D;40000
```

Output:
2

my solution->

```
f=`awk -v s=0 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{if(NR>1){s+=$3;row++}}END{print s/row}' $file`;

awk -v a="$f" 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{if(NR!=1 && $3<a)c++}END{print c}' $file;
```

This is what i have tried so far
but output comes out to be
0

Answer (score 3):

This one-liner should solve the problem:

```
awk -F';' 'NR>1{e[$1]=$3;s+=$3}
      END{avg=s/(NR-1);for(x in e)if(e[x]<avg)c++;print c}' file
```

If you run it with your example file, it is gonna print:

```
2
```

### explanation:

- `NR>1` skip the header
- `e[$1]=$3;s+=$3` : build a hashtable, and sum the salarays
- `END{avg=s/(NR-1);` : calc the averge
- `for(x in e)if(e[x]<avg)c++;print c` :go through the hashtables, count the element, which value `< avg` and output.

Comment: Solution is working perfect!                                                                                                                 one question in my solution even if  i replace ":" with ";" still the output comes out to be 0                  it feels like the second line of code {if(NR!=1 && $3<a)c++} is not working

Comment: @chirag When you replaced `:` with `;` in both lines, try `echo "f=$f"` after the first command.

Comment: @chirag you didn't use the `$f` you created in the first shot. btw, generally speaking, if we can solve a problem in a single process, we should use one process.

Comment: @WalterA output comes out to be  f=32500

Comment: @Kent can you please refer some course or sites or books from where i can learn more of awk scripting.

Comment: @chirag https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html would be the best.

Comment: This will work if the file is relatively small. If the file is large the hash structure is inefficient.

Comment: @NinjaGaiden yes, it depends on the definition of the "small".  if it is a huge file, and the size > memory.. we have to think about another approach. Otherwise, I think hashtable is efficient. (`O(1)`)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=";"
}
FNR==NR{
  if(FNR>1)
  {
    total+=$NF
    count++
  }
  next
}
FNR==1{
  avg=total/count
}
avg>$NF
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is fine except it's setting `FS=":"`; it should be setting `FS=";"` since that is what is separating your fields in the input.

Comment: Even on replacing  ":" with ";" still the output comes out to be 0 it feels like the second line of code {if(NR!=1 && $3<a)c++} is not working

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I cut and pasted your code and your input and update the `FS=` in two places and I get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

```
avg=$(awk -F";" 'NR>1 { s+=$3;i++} END { print s/i }' f)
awk -v avg=$avg -F";" 'NR>1 && $3<avg'  f
```

1) Ignore header and compute Average, avg

2) Ignore header and if salary is less than avg print

Answer (score 0):

```sh
file=$1
salary=`sed "s/;/ /" $file | sed "s/;/ /" | awk '{print $3}' | tail -n+2`
sum=0
n=0

for line in $salary
do
    ((sum+=line))
    ((n++))
done

avg=$((sum / n))
count=0

for line in $salary
do
    if [ $line -lt $avg ]
    then
         ((count++))
    fi
done

echo "No. of Emp : $count"
```